Paid Membership Pro Plugin with PayPal Express: 'Processing...' Message but No Action
I'm encountering an issue while integrating the Paid Membership Pro plugin(Paid Memberships Pro - Add PayPal Express Add On) with PayPal Express as the payment gateway on my website.Upon clicking the PayPal pay button, the system displays a 'processing...' message, but no further action occurs.
(There is just the PayPal button on checkout page)
I followed the steps outlined in the official documentation provided by PayPal for API credentials setup (https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/apiCredentials/) and configured the PayPal IPN accordingly.
I've ensured that the API credentials are correctly set up in the Paid Membership Pro payment gateway settings, and the PayPal IPN is configured correctly. Despite this, the payment process does not proceed beyond the 'processing...' message.
Could someone please provide insights or assistance on resolving this issue? Any guidance or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
